# Is there a relationship between 1 John 4:18 and Revelation 21:8?

Tags: revelation, 1-john

1 John 4:18 (ASV):

> 18. There is no fear in love: but perfect love casteth out fear, because fear hath punishment; **and he that feareth is not made perfect in love.**

Revelation 21:8 (ASV):

> 8. But for **the fearful**,  and unbelieving, and abominable, and murderers, and fornicators, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all liars, their part {cf15i shall be} in the lake that burneth with fire and brimstone; which is the second death.

Is there a relationship between 1 John 4:18, and Revelation 21:8?.

I mean: the fearful (Cowardly) of Revelation 21:8 may be explained, or interpreted as those who are not made perfect in love of 1 John 4:18.

I am not talking about verbal link between the two verses, I am talking about exegetical or hermeneutic relationship between the two verses.

How does who fear is not perfected in Love?

Answer (score 4):

I struggle to see a direct link between 1 John 4:18 and Rev 21:8 other than a single word (in the KJV and its imitators).

In 1 John 4:18, "fear" and its cognate relatives occur four times as:

- Φόβος (Phobos) [twice], Noun - Nominative Masculine Singular
- φόβον (phobon) [once], Noun - Accusative Masculine Singular
- φοβούμενος (phoboumenos) [once], Verb - Present Participle Middle or Passive - Nominative Masculine Singular

In Rev 21:8 the word translated "fear" (in the KJV) is actually, δειλοῖς (deilois) which is "cowardly", Adjective - Dative Masculine Plural.

Thus, there appears to be no verbal link between these two texts at all.

The last part of the question about the relationship between hatred and fear needs a Bible reference to frame a question for this site, so I will not address it here.

Comment: I agree with the lack of connection. I also agree with not answering when a Bible reference is not given. (+1).